# 802.11n/a (5GHz only) access point not visible to my laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, 802.11n

I have a relatively new [Toshiba laptop](http://reviewunit.com/toshiba-satellite-r630-notebook-review-and-specifications/) which supposedly supports 802.11a, so I'd assume 5GHz wireless networks should not be a problem.

My router supports the 802.11n and lower, it's an AVM 7270 VoIP router.
I am close to a lot of other wireless networks in my apartment, so 2.4GHz is almost carpeted.
Today I decided to give the 5GHz a go and switched to 802.11n/a on my router.

But then the network disappeared.
Am I doing something wrong? IPv6 is turned off in my adapter. It's a Broadcom 802.11n.

Comment: I believe it is only n that is broadcast on the 5ghz band for routers that support that function.  Your issue is that your wireless card doesn't support the 5ghz protocol.  You can buy wireless micro dongles that do if you really want to use the 5ghz band.

Comment: Nah, not THAT direly necessary.. There are a lot of APs in my neighbourhood, and when all of them are active in the evening I experience connection drops. But I could switch to my desktop anytime I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was informed incorrectly.

The Toshiba guy on the phone has corrected the spec that the Broadcom chip only supports b/g/n.

Therefore, no 5-Ghz bandwidth.